# Linux - How to install osmdroid libraries for android studio with Gradle?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am trying to do a tutorial for making an Android application using osmdroid with android Studio, but I didn't succeed to use the library I download on https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

My questions are following :

1. Where do I have to put the folder download at: github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid ? I don't find any libs folder in home/android/sdk.
2. Which version I have to put in this command:

   ```
   dependencies { 
     compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE):release‌​@aar'
   }
   ```

   instead of `INSERT_VERSION_HERE`. I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps at https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/README.md

You don't have to download anything manually. Open your `build.gradle` and add the following lines (or amend your already existing sections):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
}
```

For a list of released osmdroid versions see https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases. Currently the newest release is 5.6.5 (as of Feb 4th, 2017).